# How to move a database to my application folder

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, path

Ok so my question is probably a dumb one. I created an application(C# WindowForms) that uses a database created to a default folder "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA" and now I need to move that database to my application folder so I can run my project from any device. How can I do that ? 
I should simply move the database in a specific folder from project like resources ? 
If so, how will look the path , something like this string path = @"example.mdf"; ? 
Thank you!

Comment: You do know MS SQL Server 10.5 is not going to run on "any" device.

Comment: Hmm so I can't use the database file without a server opened ? I mean just copy the database file into my application's Resources folder and use it on any device ?

Comment: How is your device going to use it without a database application? How is the device going to interface with the data? I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'll give an example to make it more clear to understand.

Comment: I want to make an application for my C# class that uses a database. The problem is, if I want to go with my project and run it on my lab class I'm pretty sure that my application won't load any data from my database because the path is wrong ( the path is the one from my PC -C:\Exemaple\Example.mdf ). How can I manage that ? Is there any way to move the used database file to my application folder, and when I run the project will know that the database is there and will load the data? This is how I think, if I'm wrong just tell me

Answer (score 0):

You need a local databaase file:

You can explore basic tasks, such as adding tables and defining columns, by using Visual Studio to create and update a local database file in SQL Server Express LocalDB, which Local Data Overview describes. After you finish this walkthrough, you can discover more advanced capabilities by using your local database as a starting point for other walkthroughs that require it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx